# EF Core querying header, two one-to-many tables and a many-to-many between the two together in one shot

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, orm

We have 4 models which looks like this:

```
Assignment             { Id, Title }
AssignmentCourse       { AssignmentId, CourseId, other fields .... }
AssignmentUser         { AssignmentId, UserId, other fields .... }
AssignmentUserCourse   { AssignmentId, CourseId, UserId }
```

Assignment to AssignmentCourse is one to many
Assignment to AssignmentUser is one to many
AssignmentCourse to AssignmentUserCourse is one to many
AssignmentUser to AssignmentUserCourse is one to many
AssignmentUserCourse is the many to many between AssignmentUser and AssignmentCourse

The mapping I have is as follows:

```cs
modelBuilder
    .Entity<AssignmentUser>().HasKey(p => new { p.AssignmentId, p.UserId });
modelBuilder
    .Entity<AssignmentUser>()
    .HasOne(x => x.User)
    .WithMany(x => x.AssignmentUsers)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
modelBuilder
    .Entity<AssignmentUser>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Assignment)
    .WithMany(x => x.AssignmentUsers)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.AssignmentId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

modelBuilder
    .Entity<AssignmentCourse>().HasKey(p => new { p.AssignmentId, p.CourseId });
modelBuilder
    .Entity<AssignmentCourse>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Course)
    .WithMany(x => x.AssignmentCourse)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.CourseId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
modelBuilder
    .Entity<AssignmentCourse>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Assignment)
    .WithMany(x => x.AssignmentCourse)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.AssignmentId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

modelBuilder
    .Entity<AssignmentUserCourse>().HasKey(p => new { p.AssignmentId, p.UserId, p.CourseId });
modelBuilder
    .Entity<AssignmentUserCourse>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Assignment)
    .WithMany(x => x.AssignmentUserCourse)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.AssignmentId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
modelBuilder
    .Entity<AssignmentUserCourse>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Course)
    .WithMany(x => x.AssignmentUserCourse)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.CourseId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
modelBuilder
    .Entity<AssignmentUserCourse>()
    .HasOne(x => x.User)
    .WithMany(x => x.AssignmentUserCourse)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

My problem is that when I do the following

```cs
_dbContext
  .Assignment
  .Include(x => x.AssignmentCourse)
  .Include(x => x.AssignmentUser)
  .Include(x => x.AssignmentUserCourse)
```

EF is generating a query that looks like this:

```sql
 SELECT [a].*
 FROM [Assignments] AS [a]
 LEFT JOIN [AssignmentUser] AS [a0] ON [a].[Id] = [a0].[AssignmentId]
 LEFT JOIN [AssignmentCourse] AS [a1] ON [a].[Id] = [a1].[AssignmentId]
 LEFT JOIN [AssignmentUserCourse] AS [a2] ON [a].[Id] = [a2].[AssignmentId]
```

If assignmentUser and assignmentCourse are not joined on assignmentUserCourse, then result of this gets extremely big extremely fast. I understand there is a way I can rewrite that query to look like this:

```
_dbContext
  .AssignmentUserCourse
  .Include(x => x.AssignmentCourse)
  .Include(x => x.AssignmentUser)
  .Include(x => x.Assignment)
```

But is there anyway I can start with Assignment model (which is my aggregate root) and join the others in one LINQ statement?

Comment: Is Assignment your aggregate root?  it seems to me that your aggregate root is your Course with will have WorkItems and Student users.  Then an Assignments hang off the User e.g. a WorkItem being assigned to a student in the Course.  Just seems like you model is off.

Comment: Assignment is the aggregate root.